# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Tags: java, ruby, ubuntu-12.04, jruby, shoes

I am beginner in shoes app, when I was trying to run a shoes app in the Ubuntu 12.04 terminal using `shoes samples/test22.rb` I'm getting this error:

> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again.

So how can I solve this or some one help me to run a simple shoes app in ubuntu and make a desktop app?

Comment: I've regretfully downvoted on this question. It's partly due to the request for urgency - we ask that no-one regards their questions as more important than the others - and partly because on a number of your answers, you have not replied, voted or accepted. If you can respond in some fashion to people who help, I am sure they will appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are running shoes4. It runs fine for me on ubuntu 14.04, so let's figure out the difference.

First, posting samples/test22.rb would be nice as test22.rb does not exist in the shoes repo and even sample22.rb does not exist (anymore).

E.g. important factors that could lead to this crash are the shoes version, the JRuby version and the JDK version.

Here are my values:

```
tobi@tobi-desktop ~/github/shoes4 $ bin/shoes -v
Shoes 4.0.0.pre4
tobi@tobi-desktop ~/github/shoes4 $ jruby -v
jruby 1.7.20 (1.9.3p551) 2015-05-04 3086e6a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_79-b14 +jit [linux-amd64]
tobi@tobi-desktop ~/github/shoes4 $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
tobi@tobi-desktop ~/github/shoes4 $ uname -a
Linux tobi-desktop 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For 12.04 my personal guess would be an outdated JVM version on which SWT does not run anymore.