# I'd like to understand things behind the scenes: Failed to write core dump

Tags: java

I was going to start Eclipse from the terminal, but ran into this error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000038d6e08e83, pid=6018, tid=47814740359488 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_76-b13) (build
1.7.0_76-b13) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.76-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) Problematic frame: C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x8e83] Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

I'd like to fully understand why this happens, not simply to run this command that it shows me.

I know there's a question: [Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288264/failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled-to-enable-core-dumping)
but nobody answered yet.
So please shed some light on this, your help and time is deeply appreciated!

#### Three questions:

1. why the core is dumped?
2. why core dumps are disabled on this machine
3. what the effects of ulimit -c unlimited are?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're question is. Are you asking why the core is dumped, why core dumps are disabled on this machine, or what the effects of `ulimit -c unlimited` are?

Comment: Great question! Thanks for the clarification to help me sort my thinking process. Actually all three questions. I'll reformat my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you gave I assume it couldn't write a core dump because it would have been too big in terms of file size, at least beyond your ulimit limits. Ld-Linux is the shared library loader, its job is to load other shared libraries. If you type ulimit at the command line it will tell you what limits are set

```
$ ulimit
```

Maybe 2 Gigabytes and your eclipse is taking more than that, possible with a 64 bit JVM.

The sigsegv is eclipse or at least the JVM trying to do something with memory it shouldn't. That is accessing protected memory. This could be writing to read only memory or a pointer falling off the end of an allocated buffer. Do you get the same error if you restart eclipse?

If you get a core dump you can use a debugger such as gdb to analyze what went wrong.

```
gdb <executable_path> <coredump_file_path>
```

The core dump will be a .pid file. That would tell you more about the crash, maybe a strcpy() that has overflowed a buffer.

Comment: Yes, I do get the same error once I restarted eclipse. But after running $ulimit -c unlimited, I was able to open Eclipse. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Ok without limits eclipse runs ok? That's interesting.

Comment: Yes, I don't really understand why. Any clues please?

Comment: What does ulimit report without being set to unlimited (normally when you reboot it should get reset to the default value) ?